# Solve the polynomial solution of two differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I am learning and need to solve a polynomial function solution $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ that satisfies the following differential equation constraints:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{a} g(\sqrt{a}  ) & = h(\sqrt{a} )\\
h'(\sqrt{a} )g(\sqrt{a} )&=h(\sqrt{a} ) g'(\sqrt{a} )\\
\end{align}$$
$a$ is a positive number here.

I am trying to substitute the first equation and the derivative of the first equation into the second equation：
$$h'(\sqrt{a} )=\sqrt{a} g'(\sqrt{a} )+g(\sqrt{a} )$$
But I find it doesn't seem right to do so. I'm not sure what to do next to solve this problem.

Comment: Why using $\sqrt{a}$ instead of just $x$ since $a$ without the square roots appears nowhere ??

Comment: Is this a differential equation or a condition that has to be satisfied in one discrete point?

Comment: The problem is the second case you mentioned “a condition that has to be satisfied in one discrete point”. here a is a number

Comment: @LutzLehmann The problem is the second case you mentioned “a condition that has to be satisfied in one discrete point”. here a is a number

Comment: So given $g$ and $g'$ at the point $x=\sqrt a$, these equations determine the values of $h$ and $h'$ at the same point. That is not sufficient to determine a unique solution, even in the polynomials. It seems some information is missing for this task.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I don't think there is a unique solution to this problem. But how can I calculate several of these solutions?

Comment: Set $g(x)=g_0+g_1x$, then minimally $h(x)=g_0x+g_1x^2$ with the condition $g_1c=h'(c)=g_0+2g_1c$, meaning that $g(c)=0$, all with $c=\sqrt{a}$. Similarly you can construct higher degree examples. Of course the first equation means in general only $h(x)=xg(x)+(x-c)v(x)$ giving even more freedom of design.